# how to set the custom options panel in android?

Tags: android

how to set the custom options panel in android?

Comment: I think your question is too specific.

Answer (score 1):

Settings in Android applications are [stored using `Preferences`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).  As well as ways to get and set Preferences, the API also provides [widgets for building your options panel](http://d.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary.html).

Such an options panel is normally created as a [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).  If you have a look at the [API Demo sample application](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) provided with the SDK you can find an example of [how to populate a `PreferenceActivity` from an XML file](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/PreferencesFromXml.html) and [how to populate a `PreferenceActivity` using Java code](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/PreferencesFromCode.html).